# XPages, Javascript - Parse JSON and return values of all keys

Tags: javascript, json, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

Through a REST API using the eric restful, I was able to return the following JSON.

```js
{
 "\"\"": "",
 "\"AAC\"": "London Marketing",
 "\"AAD\"": "Broadstairs Marketing",
 "\"AAE\"": "Matalan Marketing",
 "\"AAF\"": "Sittingbourne Design"
}
```

I can return only one of the keys.

```js
var custList = function () {
 importPackage(com.eric.restful); 
 
 try{
  var myDoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("db","");  
  var urlStr = myDoc.getItemValueString("mData");
  
  var custListLiteral = CustRestConsumer.GetRestData(urlStr);
  print("list literal: " + custListLiteral);
  
  var getContact = JSON.parse(custListLiteral);
  print("value of AAC: " + getContact["\"AAC\""]);
  
 }catch(e){
  print("error getting list: " + e.toString());
 }
 return getContact["\"AAC\""]; //returns London Marketing
}
```

```js
custList();
//returns London Marketing
```

I will like to be able to return all values without passing any key.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks Paul for that response, I have now implemented the map by adding the method below to the CustRestConsumer class:

```js
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
private static final Type TT_mapStringString = new TypeToken<Map<String,String>>(){}.getType();

public static Map<String, String> getJsonArray(String json) {
    Map<String, String> ret = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (json == null || json.isEmpty())
        return ret;
     return gson.fromJson(json, TT_mapStringString);
}
```

But when I called it in the javascript function below:

```js
var custList = function () {
 importPackage(com.eric.restful); 
 
 try{
  var myDoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("db","");  
  var urlStr = myDoc.getItemValueString("mData");
  
  var custListLiteral = CustRestConsumer.GetRestData(urlStr);
  print("list literal: " + custListLiteral);
  
  var mapList = fromJson(custListLiteral,TT_mapStringString);
  Map<String, String> strObj = CustRestConsumer.jsonToMapStringString(mapList);
  print("strObj: " + strObj);
  
  //var getContact = JSON.parse(custListLiteral);
  //print("value of AAC: " + getContact["\"AAC\""]);
  
 }catch(e){
  print("error getting list: " + e.toString());
 }
 return strObj;
}
```

I get an error below:

```
error getting list: 'TT_mapStringString' not found
```

Will appreciate any input. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: http://dontpanic82.blogspot.sk/2010/09/xpages-ssjs-code-snippet-that-lets-you.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to utilise Java libraries, the good news is IBM have already done a lot of that work for you. Check out the `com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonParser` and `com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonFactory` classes. These allow a JSON string to be parsed into a Java Map. In OpenNTF Domino API Demo Servlet, I use the following code:

```
final Map<String, Object> jsonAsObj = (Map<String, Object>) JsonParser.fromJson(JsonJavaFactory.instance, body);
```

"body" is the JSON string, pulled from the REST service input. You may get problems with the first element, because it has no property name, but it has no value either.

Comment: I implemented the Map, but had an error which I have added above. Please have a look at the snippet of my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: TT_mapStringString is private in your class, so it's not accessible to anything (including the SSJS) outside. You need to add a getter and use that instead. The line after that will fail because `Map<String, String> strObj` is Java syntax in SSJS, you'll need to declare in SSJS using `var`

Comment: Paul: what is your data source and how do you access it? via http? which method do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. This is just to convert JSON data to a Java Map, what's done with it either side is out of scope. The JSON data may be stored in a field, may be sent via HTTP POST, may be retrieved from e.g. Cloudant. Here's the source code for the line I quoted https://stash.openntf.org/projects/ODA/repos/demo-servlet/browse/org.openntf.domino.demoServlet/src/org/openntf/domino/demoServlet/HelloWorldResource.java#145